# Unable to solve exponent rules problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working in a book that I have and I am on the exponents and logarithms section. There is just one problem I am unable to solve.

Show that $(xy)^{x^{y}}=x^{xy}$ implies $y=1$ for $x>0.$

I put this in a graphing calculator, and it works, but I have no clue where to even start with showing it.

Answer (score 0):

Prove it by contraposition, differ between $|y| < 1$ and $|y| > 1$ and try to use monotony properties (of multiplication and exponentiation) to get ineqalities.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Could you give an example of monotony properties?

Comment: E. g: Let $y > 1$. Then, for all $x \in mathbbR_{>0}: x < x \times y$.